# 'Write; statement without a lot of spaces

Tags: fortran

The `write` function does print the parameters with a lot of spaces between columms, this is giving me a very huge file in the end. so How do I trim the output, to like a single space.

```
open(unit=1,file='gfortran.txt')
write(1,ERR=1001)1,2,3
```

Comment: @MathieuImbert what's so strange about it?

Comment: Not strange, just personal history, It feels like home :)

Comment: Would you like single spaces between values of varying lengths? Thats more challenging - I started to cook something up but realise you probably dont really want a convoluted answer..

Comment: @george exactly, I need to separate values of different lengths with a single space, just like a CSV file. Because I'm dealing with very large files on a Super Computer Cluster, and this spaces are wasting GBs of storage. I noticed that post trimming spaces are saving about 70%

Comment: The I0 format is the answer, See M.S.B.'s comment below.

Answer (score 5):

You need to take control of the output formatting using Fortran's *edit descriptors*.  If you just want to write 3 integers on a line then you could use

```
write(1,fmt='(3i2)',err=1001) 1, 2, 3
```

which will write the integers into 2-character wide fields in the output file.  There are many variations of the edit descriptors you should become familiar with.  A couple of examples:

```
fmt='(i4.2)'  ! 1 integer is written into a 4-character wide field, with at least 2 digits so a leading 0 is written if necessary
fmt='(6f9.4)' ! 6 reals are written into 9-character fields, with 4 digits after the decimal point
```

There's a lot more besides this, your compiler documentation will explain everything.

Comment: If you don't know how large the integers are and want to use the minimum number of digits you can use the I0 format.  So: 3(1X, I0) or *(1X, I0)

Comment: oh now I feel really silly for manually generating format strings..At least I learned something!

Comment: If, as one of your comments above suggests, you are concerned about the space occupied by your files you should be writing binary files, what Fortran calls 'unformatted'.  But that's another topic.

Answer (score 3):

This is just an explanatory comment in addition to what High Performance Mark has written. If you do not provide an explicit format specifier in the `WRITE` statement, the so-called *list directed output* is being used. Each Fortran processor (the Fortran word for compiler) is free to choose an output format that will guarantee that every element in the list will be printed in its entirety. This often leads to very wide (and compiler dependent) fields being used.